# condition in SELECT command

Tags: php, mysql

I have user table with fields username,student name, class where it stores values as

```
username      studentname     class
--------      -----------     ------ 
ABC           Prudhvi           1
XYZ           Vishwa            2
SSS           Priya             3
```

I'm displaying the database records from this user table by using grid table.

```
SELECT * FROM user.
```

Now, here if class=1 i want to display class name in grid as Nursery & if class=2 it should display as pre-school....

I want the displaying grid table as follows

```
username      studentname     class
--------      -----------     ------ 
ABC           Prudhvi           Nursery
XYZ           Vishwa            Pre-school
SSS           Priya             Kindergarten
```

But i want to display the class names differently while displaying without changing it's values in database.

I tried using switch codition,but didn't worked.

Please help me.

Comment: You need to use in the foreach an if statement where you check if the class is 1/2/3 and then show the correct value which should printed

Comment: Why not create a new table with that values (class names) and join with this table?

Comment: @Sal00m also good suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to make a second table that contains the class mappings:

```
ID|Class
1 |Nursery
2 |Preschool
...
```

Then you join your first table on the new classTable and select the values you need.

Comment: i need to edit in the coding itself without adding any new column to the table..i used switch condition but i'm not geting how to fetch those conditional values into grid table

Comment: @user3313444 You do not want to add an other _database table_? Why would you wish to have static coding in the DB query? I would recommend doing the mapping in php in instead. Maybe I do not understand what the actual problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to reconsider your table structure. Not only will this make your query simpler but will conform to database normalisation.
http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Create another table which contains the class names and then do a simple INNER JOIN, to join these two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT username,
   CASE class
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Nursury'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Pre-school'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Kindergarden'
   END CASE AS 'classname'
FROM user
```

You can learn more about `case` on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html
and also I agree with others in normalizing your tables

Comment: `classname` is an arbitrary field name only, it can be anything you want it to be. I suggest you run this on an sql client such as PHPMyAdmin on your table and see the result. Then do it in PHP. If your sql gives an error, post it here.

Comment: hi..after adding the CASE in the query..edit and delete functions or not working on the table records..plz guide what need to be done for those...thank you

Comment: hi..sorry for the delay..below are the codes:                     editing:
$sql = "update p_user_profile set username='$username',password='$password',studentname='$studentname',class='$class',parentname='$parentname',timestamp='$timestamp' where p_id='$p_id'";       
Deleting:
$sql = "delete from p_user_profile where p_id=$p_id";

Comment: Ok, what you need to do is to select the class as is next to `case` statement, so you have both the class id, and the names you have given to them. Then when updating or editing, use the class code, and when displaying use the class name. So your `select` should be something like this `SELECT username, class, CASE class WHEN 1 THEN 'Nursury' WHEN 2 THEN 'Pre-school' WHEN 3 THEN 'Kindergarden' END CASE AS 'classname' FROM user`. Now you have both class id and some name to display for them. Use that id for deleting, updating and editing. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi..as u suggested i used the below code for deleting :  $dropdownlist1 = $_REQUEST['class'];
$dropdownlist2 = $dropdownlist1.value;                              $sql = "delete from p_user_profile where id = $dropdownlist2";             but it's not working...plz chk

Comment: echo your sql query after you build it, then copy the query and run it directly with an SQL client, such as PHPMyAdmin. Check if it gives you any error.

Comment: hi Mahdi..i checked in PHPMYADMIN..every thing works fine there..but i'm unable to work with edit & delete functionalities..plz help in this why the case in select is effecting the edit & delete functions..

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was away. I seriously don't know what's wrong now. Your queries all look fine. I am not sure how SO works in terms of chat, but if it is possible we can arrange a chat and discuss it and check your code thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Case in select query. e.g.

```
SELECT username, studentname,     
CASE(class)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Nursery'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Pre-school'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Kindergarten'
END AS 'className'
FROM `user`;
```

Comment: it's not working..i used the below code as given by you..plz chk  $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from p_user_profile where " . $where );
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
 $result["total"] = $row[0];
 //$rs = mysql_query("select * from p_user_profile where " . $where . " limit $offset,$rows");

 $rs = mysql_query("SELECT username, studentname, parentname,
    CASE(class)
     WHEN 1 THEN 'Nursery' 
     WHEN 2 THEN 'Pre-school'
     WHEN 3 THEN 'Kindergarten'
     END AS 'class' FROM 'user_profile'");

Comment: It can be done like this, but this is not good database design.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for posting the reply..

The below code is working fine..

```
SELECT username, password, studentname, parentname, timestamp, 
CASE class
    WHEN  '1' THEN  'Pre_nursery M - Gold fish'
    WHEN  '2' THEN  'Pre-nursery LMP - Ducklings'
    WHEN  '3' THEN  'Nursery M - Doves'
    WHEN  '4' THEN  'Nursery M Sejal - Parrots'
    WHEN  '5' THEN  'Nursery LMP - Koels'
    WHEN  '6' THEN  'K1 - Cuckoos'
    WHEN  '7' THEN  'K1 LMP Blue jays'
    WHEN  '8' THEN  'K2 - White doves'
    WHEN  '9' THEN  'K2 LMP - Penguins'
    WHEN  '10' THEN  'Extended - Peacocks'
END AS class
FROM user_profile
```